# [Laptop]: what is the performance difference between intel i7 4th generation with 8th generation laptop?

Tags: laptop, processor, intel

I am planning to purchase 4th generation Intel® Core™ i7-4600U 2.10GHz 2.70GHz model. Also, I am thinking of latest version of 8th generation if it has lot of performance difference. Regarding this I have 2 questions.

1. What is the performance difference between Intel i7 4th generation with 8th generation?
2. What is the meaning of 2.10GHz 2.70GHz. Is it related to speed or something else?

Guide me whether **intel i7 4th generation** is it sufficient enough or **8th generation** is better?

**Note: Main usage is Python programming for data science point of purpose, not for graphical and gaming related purpose.**

Comment: I have closed this question as it is asking for a hardware recommendation, but rather a list of differences between two things. You would receive better answers if you listed out your requirements and budget, and let us help you pick the best item for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your budget allows you to upgrade to i7 8th gen then i will recommend you to go for it. But this does not mean that i7 4th gen is troublesome it's one of the good processors till today and for programming it won't be any trouble so if you want you can easily carry out your work on i7 4th gen. 
2.10 GHz is meant for processor's clock speed with which it processes data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable response.. Now I have idea to take decision.. Thanks..